# Error(s) generating password

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, libgcrypt

I am using PBKDF2 to generate a key from a password using SHA-256

```
int genKeyFromPass()
{
    int i; 
    void *pwd, *salt = "someRandomSalt";
    unsigned char keyBuffer[16]; 
    size_t saltLen, keySize = 16;
    gpg_error_t errStatus; 
    unsigned long iterations = 1024; 
    printf("Enter the password to generate key: ");
    scanf("%s", pwd);
    errStatus = gcry_kdf_derive(pwd, strlen(pwd), GCRY_KDF_PBKDF2, GCRY_MD_SHA512, salt, strlen(salt), iterations, keySize, keyBuffer);
    if(errStatus != 0)
    {
        printf("Error generating key from password!\n");
        printf("Error no: %d and message: %s\n ", errStatus, gcry_strerror(errno)); 
    }
    printf("Key: ");        
    printf("%s", keyBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. My function always prints "Error generating key from password"  but when I print the error message, it prints success. Why am I getting error to generate password?
2. I don't know the value of `keysize` is suppposed to have. Can anyone explain what do I need to put in that parameter?
3. When I run this code I get segmentation fault at the line `gcry_kdf_derive`. Why would that happen?

Thanks.

Comment: It's `gcry_strerror(errStatus)`, not `gcry_strerror(errno)`. Fix that and see what the error is.

Comment: I tried that too but I got the same result.

Comment: keyBuffer should be an actual buffer, not a NULL pointer.  E.g., `unsigned char keyBuffer[32];`.  I'm guessing your key size is 32 because AES-256 has a 256-bit key, which is 32 bytes.  Also, don't declare things as `void *`.  Raw bytes should be held in an `unsigned char` array.

Comment: I changed the code to have `unsigned char keyBuffer[16]` as I would be using AES128